# Bypass prompt for a parameter to cmake in dockerfile for Ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu, cmake, dockerfile

I am building up a docker image for phython project in which I am using cmake. while building docker I see this command taking long time

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cmake

I see on the power-shell that it is asking for Geographic area, but I cannot enter it.

```
questions will narrow this down by presenting a list of cities, representing the time zones in which they are located.

 1. Africa 4. Australia 7. Atlantic 10. Pacific 13. Etc
 2. America 5. Arctic 8. Europe 11. SystemV 
 3. Antarctica 6.Asia 9. Indian 12.US 

Geographic area:
```

How can I pass these parameter in dockerfile itself, so it's not being stopped to wait for this input.

I have checked similar questions, but its not clear how to do it for this package on ubuntu. Can someone pls explain how this works for docker where I can bypass prompt.

Comment: ([Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  You should almost never include screen shots of terminal windows in your questions.)